# Get element scroll percentage with top and bottom of viewport as anchor points

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the percentage of an element scrolled, but with the top of the viewport being 0% and the bottom being 100%. 
This codepen scrolls down the green .wrapper element setting the percentage based on the top of the viewport. I would like for it to be 100 percentage when the bottom (and not the top) of the viewport passes the bottom point of the .wrapper (retaining the top of the viewport as the beginning point).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = $(".wrapper");
  var wrapperHeight = el.outerHeight();
  var wrapperTop = el.offset().top;
  var wrapperBottom = el.offset().top + wrapperHeight;


  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrolled > wrapperTop && scrolled < wrapperBottom) {
      var percentageScrolled = ((scrolled - wrapperTop) / wrapperHeight) * 100;
      $(".scrolled").text(parseInt(percentageScrolled));
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.page {
  height: 10000px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 1000px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 1500px;
  background: green;
}

.scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrapper">

  </div>
</div>

<p class="scrolled"></p>
```

https://codepen.io/tornadokent/pen/wLyLvr

Answer (score -5):

This looks like a Job for [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

With this you can trigger a callback function whenever one or multiple elements (based on a selector) become visible or are leaving the page.

First you must create the observer:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Then you set a target that should be watched:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
observer.observe(target);
```

After that you just have to define what should happen for each element that enters (or in your case leaves) the viewport:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I need the percentage for the calculation I am trying to do.

Comment: You get the percentage from Intersection Observer. So no excuse to not use it.

Comment: Downvoting this because IntersectionObserver will only trigger when the target enters the viewport (controllable via threshold). You do not get the scroll percentage on demand and it doesn't solve the problem where the element is already in the viewport and you want to know how much of the element has been scrolled past which is what OP (and anyone else who would land here from Google) would want to know.